# Microsoft Graph API - Application is not supported for this API version

Tags: c#, azure, authentication, xamarin.forms, microsoft-graph-api

I'm trying to make this Graph API sample work :
https://github.com/microsoftgraph/xamarin-csharp-snippets-sample

I registered my app in Azure, got the Application-id and set it into the App.cs file from the sample.
Everytime I try simple operations, I get this message :

> Users.Get Me failed. Exception: AADSTS70001: Application 'My-APP-ID'
>   is not supported for this API version.

I tried modifying the AuthenticationHelper.cs file to go from new

```
GraphServiceClient("https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0",
```

to :

```
new GraphServiceClient("https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.6",
```

To try and get the 1.6 API version, hoping the issue would come from there.
But I still get the same message over and over.

I chose this sample because all I have to do is set the App ID (I thought so) but I can't get it to work.

Has anyone experienced this issue ?
What should I change to get it to work so that I can use the graph API in my "real" solution.

Thank you.

Comment: Could you provide the actual code that causes this exception?

Comment: i had got similar issue, tried registering the app as per the documentation provided https://developer.microsoft.com/enus/graph/docs/concepts/auth_register_app_v2 and replacing the client id in the samples and it worked . Hope this helps !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Graph only has two versions `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0` and `https://graph.microsoft.com/beta`. I'm not sure where you are getting `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.6` from but this is *not* a valid Graph URI.